# Why do I get typeerror when I use variable in class python?

Tags: python, class, attributes

I have this program to bank account with a class. It is supposed to deposit a balance into the account as you can see at a1.deposit(1000) and then update the balance on the account.

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self,first_name,last_name,number,balance):

        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.number = number
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self,amount):
        self.balance += amount

    def withdraw(self,amount):
        self.withdraw -= amount

    def print_info(self):
        first=self.first_name
        last=self.last_name
        number=self.number
        balance = self.balance
        s=f'{first} {last}, {number}, balance: {balance}'
        print(s)

a1= BankAccount('Gang', 'Land', '19371554951', '20000')

a1.deposit(1000)

print(a1.balance)
```

I dont understand whats wrong because I get only type error:

```
self.balance += amount

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your error is with this line :

```
a1= BankAccount('Gang', 'Land', '19371554951', '20000')
```

if you are wanting to increase the value of the balance, then you need to initiate that variable as an integer or float. So just remove the '' around the 20000 and try again.